# Schedule a task on iOS every 15-30 mins

Tags: android, ios, xcode, ios7

I have an application that i have developed for ios, android and windows phone 8.  The client now requires that the application checks if there is any data to be uploaded to the server every 15-30 minutes and if so, upload it. This is needed because the application is used in areas where there will not be an internet connection.  The user adds data into the application and that data needs to be uploaded to the server once an internet connection is available

I have implemented this on android using the AlarmManager to schedule the application to check if there is any data and upload it, and on windows phone i used a PeriodicTask.

Is there such functionality in iOS?  When i try googling this, i get many different things appear like NSURLSession, Background Transfer Service and others that say it ain't possible.

So, it is possible and what classes do i need to look into to get this working?  If i have to aim at a particular iOS version then that is fine.

Comment: *the application checks if there is any data to be uploaded to the server every 15-30 minutes and if so, upload it.* Did you mean download it ?

Comment: No, i mean upload it.  The user adds data on their device and that data then needs to be uploaded to the server.  The application allows the user to enter data without an internet connection

Answer (score 2):

You can use NSTimer:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1800.0 target:self selector:@selector(yourselector) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
```

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:)

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible, well may be. Since only specific apps can run in the background like: AudioStreamer, VOIP, Accessory companion or location tracking.

These apps can't really schedule a task. Also it would be really bad for the battery to check some server every 15-30 min.

You can use [`NSURLSessions`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLSession) to create an uploading task that will run on the background.

You will have to setup the session correctly with all the delegate methods implemented: [Background Transfer Considerations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW44).

Comment: I new data is on the device, not on the server.  The data needs to be uploaded to the server.

Comment: @user2736022: So the new data is created while your app is running correct ? So enqueue it using NSURLSession and upload it. For that 15 to 30 minute, you can use a NSTimer

Comment: @user2736022: How is this new data getting on the device? Is it create by the user? Then why do you need it to be upload every 15-30 min?

Comment: New data is added by the user into the application, but there is no guarantee that the user will have an active internet connection, as the application is used in non-serviceable areas (sewers etc).  Thus why a background service on the other platforms runs and checks every X minutes if the user has entered new data that needs to be uploaded, and uploads when an internet connection is available

Comment: You might be able to pull it off with the `NSURLSession` but no way to build a service like app that can check every so many minutes.

Comment: @rckoenes i guess that using NSURLSessions i could get the application to upload what it can, which is great, but when does a BackgroundTransfer take place? or can you implement it to check upon starting/resuming the application?  Sorry iOS programming is not really my thing...

Comment: I guess there is no way to check the connectivity of the device and Apple doe snot allow you to create a service which will do this. You only option is the `NSURLSession` to handle the request for you. This will allow the request to continue in the background and allow you app to handle it. So when it fails because of connectivity issue you can just restart the request again. My guess is that this is yout best bed.

Answer (score 0):

There are mainly 3 things to consider:
1.) Will the app remain active (visible on the device screen) for 15-20 mins. I suppose that won't be the case.
2.) When the app enters background state (not visible on the app screen, but is in the background), you can perform/schedule tasks for a maximum of 3 minutes.

3.) If the user kills the app (the app is not in background mode) then you cannot do anything.

Answer (score 0):

NSTimer *yourTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1800.0 target:self selector:@selector(YourMethod) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];

please try this ... this will work...

Comment: Even if the application is in the background?

Answer (score 0):

The upload task supports background operations by default (refer : https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlsessionuploadtask).

But that is limited to as long as the app is in memory. This is to ensure no app consumes  battery without absolute NEED.

What you can do is upload in the background mode and check for pending upload data every time you launch your app.